# R convert tidy hierarchical data frame to hierarchical list

Tags: r, list, hierarchical-data

Converting this

```
g1    g2    desc    val
A     a     1       v1
A     a     2       v2
A     b     3       v3
```

To:

```
desc    val
A
a
1       v1
2       v2
b
3       v3
```

I've converted a hierarchical data frame with two grouping levels into a structured list using a for loop. This displayed descriptions with an associated variable in a list interspersed with the group levels in order.

The purpose is to present the hierarchical data as a list so that it can be printed with formatting to distinguish the different grouping levels, using openxlsx.

Is there a more efficient base R, tidyverse or other approach to achieve this?

**For loop code**

```
tib <-  tibble(g1 = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C"),
          g2 = c("a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "c", "d", "d", "b", "b", "e", "e"),
          desc = 1:12,
          val = paste0("v", 1:12))

# Number of rows in final table
n_rows <- length(unique(tib$g1)) + length(unique(paste0(tib$g1, tib$g2))) + nrow(tib)

# create empty output tibble
output <- 
    as_tibble(matrix(nrow = n_rows, ncol = 2)) %>% 
    rename(desc = V1, val = V2) %>% 
    mutate(desc = NA_character_,
           val = NA_real_)

# loop counters
level_1 <- 0
level_2 <- 0
output_row <- 1

for(i in seq_len(nrow(tib))){

  # level 1 headings
  if(tib$g1[[i]] != level_1) {
    output$desc[[output_row]] <- tib$g1[[i]]
    output_row <- output_row + 1
    }

  # level 2 headings
  if(paste0(tib$g1[[i]], tib$g2[[i]]) != paste0(level_1, level_2)) {
    output$desc[[output_row]] <- tib$g2[[i]]
    output_row <- output_row + 1
  }

  level_1 <- tib$g1[[i]]
  level_2 <- tib$g2[[i]]

  # Description and data
  output$desc[[output_row]] <- tib$desc[[i]]
  output$val[[output_row]] <- tib$val[[i]]
  output_row <- output_row + 1

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a few packages from the `tidyverse`, we could do:

```
library(tidyverse)

# or explicitly load what you need
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)

transpose(df) %>% 
  unlist() %>% 
  stack() %>% 
  distinct(values, ind) %>% 
  mutate(detect_var = str_detect(values, "^v"),
         ind = lead(case_when(detect_var == TRUE ~ values)),
         values = case_when(detect_var == TRUE ~ NA_character_,
                            TRUE ~ values)) %>% 
  drop_na(values) %>% 
  select(values, ind) %>% 
  replace_na(list(ind = ""))
```

Returns:

> ```
>   values ind
> 1      A    
> 2      a    
> 3      1  v1
> 5      2  v2
> 7      b    
> 8      3  v3
> ```

Using `tib` data set, my solution seems to be a little slower than Plamen's:

> ```
> Unit: milliseconds
>        expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq        max neval
>         old 17.658398 18.492957 21.292965 19.396304 21.770249 133.215223   100
>  new_simple  6.742158  7.013732  7.638155  7.190095  7.759104  12.640237   100
>    new_fast  4.064907  4.266243  4.837131  4.507865  4.871533   9.442904   100
>   tidyverse  4.980664  5.326694  6.004602  5.552611  6.215129   9.923524   100
> ```

Comment: Adding `mutate(g2 = paste(g1, g2, sep = "_"))` to the beginning and `mutate(values = str_remove(values, "\\D_"))` to the end makes this work. 
The actual data includes many variables of different types associated with the desc variable. I'm struggling to adapt this code to the actual data, so have asked another question.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can simplify and slightly optimize your code like this :

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(microbenchmark)

microbenchmark(
  old = {

    tib <-  tibble(g1 = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C"),
                   g2 = c("a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "c", "d", "d", "b", "b", "e", "e"),
                   desc = 1:12,
                   val = paste0("v", 1:12))

    # Number of rows in final table
    n_rows <- length(unique(tib$g1)) + length(unique(paste0(tib$g1, tib$g2))) + nrow(tib)

    # create empty output tibble
    output <- 
      as_tibble(matrix(nrow = n_rows, ncol = 2)) %>% 
      rename(desc = V1, val = V2) %>% 
      mutate(desc = NA_character_,
             val = NA_real_)

    # loop counters
    level_1 <- 0
    level_2 <- 0
    output_row <- 1

    for(i in seq_len(nrow(tib))){

      # level 1 headings
      if(tib$g1[[i]] != level_1) {
        output$desc[[output_row]] <- tib$g1[[i]]
        output_row <- output_row + 1
      }

      # level 2 headings
      if(paste0(tib$g1[[i]], tib$g2[[i]]) != paste0(level_1, level_2)) {
        output$desc[[output_row]] <- tib$g2[[i]]
        output_row <- output_row + 1
      }

      level_1 <- tib$g1[[i]]
      level_2 <- tib$g2[[i]]

      # Description and data
      output$desc[[output_row]] <- tib$desc[[i]]
      output$val[[output_row]] <- tib$val[[i]]
      output_row <- output_row + 1

    }

  }
  ,
  new_simple = {

    tib <-  tibble(g1 = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C"),
                   g2 = c("a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "c", "d", "d", "b", "b", "e", "e"),
                   desc = 1:12,
                   val = paste0("v", 1:12)) %>%
      unite('g1g2', g1, g2, remove = F)

    tib_list <- split(tib, tib$g1g2)

    convert_group <- function(sub_df){
      tibble(
        desc = c(sub_df$g1[1], sub_df$g2[2], sub_df$desc)
        , val = c(NA, NA, sub_df$val)
      )
    }

    res_df <- bind_rows(lapply(tib_list, convert_group))
  }
  ,
  new_fast = {

    tib <-  tibble(g1 = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C"),
                   g2 = c("a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "c", "d", "d", "b", "b", "e", "e"),
                   desc = 1:12,
                   val = paste0("v", 1:12)) %>%
      unite('g1g2', g1, g2, remove = F)

    tib_list <- split(tib, tib$g1g2)

    convert_desc <- function(sub_df){ 
      c(sub_df$g1[1], sub_df$g2[2], sub_df$desc)
    }

    convert_val <- function(sub_df){ c(NA, NA, sub_df$val) }

    res_df <- tibble(
      desc = sapply(tib_list, convert_desc)
      , val = sapply(tib_list, convert_val)
    )
  }
)
```

This gives me the following output:

```
Unit: milliseconds
       expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq       max neval
        old 41.06535 43.52606 49.42744 47.29305 52.74399  76.98021   100
 new_simple 57.08038 60.65657 68.11021 63.38157 71.62398 112.24893   100
   new_fast 24.16624 26.30785 31.07178 28.38764 31.91647 148.06442   100
```

Comment: This produces g1-1, g2-1, desc1, desc2, **g1-1**, g2-1, desc3... The superfluous level 1 instance is highlighted. The required output is g1-1, g2-1, desc1, desc2,  g2-1, desc3...