# How to convert tidy hierarchical data frame to hierarchical list grid in R?

Tags: r, hierarchical-data

This is a more complex version of a previous question where I had abstracted the actual problem too much to apply the answers.
[R convert tidy hierarchical data frame to hierarchical list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49341954/r-convert-tidy-hierarchical-data-frame-to-hierarchical-list/49343053#49343053)

I've converted a hierarchical data frame with two grouping levels into a hierarchical list-grid using a for loop.

Is there a more efficient base R, tidyverse or other approach to achieve this?

In the real dataset:

- The grouping variables and description are multi word strings.
- The description preface - d# - is in the MWE for ease of checking.
- There are 14 associated variables variously of type: character, integer and double

### Rules

Group 1 and Group 2 headings to be in description column 
Group 1 headings to appear once only
Group 2 heading are children of group 1 heading, and only change when there is a new group 2 heading
Descriptions are children of group 2 headings

### From this

```
g1    g2    desc    var1       var2   var3 
A     a     d1 KS3  0.0500     2      PLs  
A     a     d2 CTI  0.0500     9      7O0  
A     b     d3 b8x  0.580      5      he2  
A     b     d4 XOf  0.180     12      XJE  
A     b     d5 ygn  0.900     11      v48  
A     c     d6 dGY  0.770      6      UcH  
A     d     d7 jpG  0.600      4      P5M  
B     d     d8 Z95  0.600     10      j6O
```

### To this

```
 desc      var1      var2  var3 
 A         
 a       
 d1 KS3   0.0500     2     PLs  
 d2 CTI   0.0500     9     7O0  
 b       
 d3 b8x   0.580      5     he2  
 d4 XOf   0.180     12     XJE  
 d5 ygn   0.900     11     v48  
 c        
d6 dGY   0.770      6     UcH  
 d          
d7 jpG   0.600      4     P5M  
 B       
 d
```

## Code

```
library(tidyverse)
library(stringi)

set.seed(2018) 

tib <-  tibble(g1 = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C"),
               g2 = c("a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "c", "d", "d", "b", "b", "e", "e"),
               desc = paste0("d", 1:12, " ", stri_rand_strings(12, 3)),
               var1 = round(runif(12), 2),
               var2 = sample.int(12),
               var3 = stri_rand_strings(12, 3))


tib

# Number of rows in final table
n_rows <- length(unique(tib$g1)) + length(unique(paste0(tib$g1, tib$g2))) + nrow(tib)

# create empty output tibble
output <- 
  as_tibble(matrix(nrow = n_rows, ncol = ncol(tib)-1)) %>% 
  rename(id = V1, desc = V2, var1 = V3, var2 = V4, var3 = V5) %>% 
  mutate(id = NA_character_,
         desc = NA_character_,
         var1 = NA_real_,
         var2 = NA_integer_,
         var3 = NA_character_)

# Loop counters
level_1 <- 0
level_2 <- 0
output_row <- 1

for(i in seq_len(nrow(tib))){

  # level 1 headings
  if(tib$g1[[i]] != level_1) {
    output$id[[output_row]] <- "g1"
    output$desc[[output_row]] <- tib$g1[[i]]
    output_row <- output_row + 1
  }

  # level 2 headings
  if(paste0(tib$g1[[i]], tib$g2[[i]]) != paste0(level_1, level_2)) {
    output$id[[output_row]] <- "g2"
    output$desc[[output_row]] <- tib$g2[[i]]
    output_row <- output_row + 1
  }

  level_1 <- tib$g1[[i]]  
  level_2 <- tib$g2[[i]] 

  # Description and data grid
  output$desc[[output_row]] <- tib$desc[[i]]
  output$var1[[output_row]] <- tib$var1[[i]]
  output$var2[[output_row]] <- tib$var2[[i]]
  output$var3[[output_row]] <- tib$var3[[i]]
  output_row <- output_row + 1

}

output
```

Comment: I don't understand your expected output. Could you please edit your post to include a more detailed explanation of the rules. Also, can you make sure that the column headers line up with the respective column. I don't know where a column starts/ends in both your sample data and expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adapting the answer from tyluRp [R convert tidy hierarchical data frame to hierarchical list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49341954/r-convert-tidy-hierarchical-data-frame-to-hierarchical-list/49343053#49343053) I've hit on a solution.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(stringi)

set.seed(2018) 

tib <-  tibble(g1 = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C"),

               g2 = c("a", "a", "b", "b", "b", "c", "d", "d", "b", "b", "e", "e"),
               desc = paste0("d", 1:12, " ", stri_rand_strings(12, 3)),
               var1 = round(runif(12), 2),
               var2 = sample.int(12),
               var3 = stri_rand_strings(12, 3))

# add unique identifier for description and variable rows
tib <- 
  tib %>%
  rowid_to_column() %>% 
  mutate(rowid = paste0("z_", rowid))

# separate tibble for variables associated with descriptions
tib_var <- 
  tib %>% 
  select(rowid, var1, var2, var3)

# code adapted from tyluRp to reorder the data and add description variables 
tib <- 
  tib %>%
  select(g1, g2, desc, rowid) %>% 
  mutate(g2 = paste(g1, g2, sep = "_")) %>% 
  transpose() %>% 
  unlist() %>% 
  stack() %>% 
  distinct(values, ind) %>% 
  mutate(detect_var = str_detect(values, "^z_"),
         ind = lead(case_when(detect_var == TRUE ~ values)),
         values = case_when(detect_var == TRUE ~ NA_character_,
                            TRUE ~ values))%>% 
  drop_na(values) %>% 
  select(values, ind) %>% 
  mutate(values = str_remove(values, "\\D_")) %>% 
  left_join(tib_var, by = c("ind" = "rowid")) %>% 
  select(-ind) %>% 
  replace_na(list(var1 = "", var2 = "", var3 = ""))
```